# Passing custom props to each styled component through Provider

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I would like to pass a custom prop (exactly: theme name as string) to each passed styled component through Provider, so it was available throughout the css definition.
ThemeProvider almost does it, but it expects object, not the string. I do not want to pass whole object with theme settings, just the name of my theme.

I do not want to use special theme prop or similar, because then I would have to it manually every single time I create new styled component. Provider seems like the best option if only it cooperated with string.

Is there any possibility to pass a string through Provider to Consumer builded in styled components?

EDIT:

[PARTIAL SOLUTION]

I found what I was looking for when I realized styled-components exports their inner context. That was it. Having access to pure react context gives you original Provider, without any 'only objects' restriction ('only objects' is a styled-components custom provider restriction).
Now I can push to each styled component exactly what I want and if I want.

```
import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components';

const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme == 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black'};
`;

const Component = props => {

  const theme = 'dark';

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
      <NextLevelComponent>
        <StyledComponent />
      </NextLevelComponent>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have this correct, from what I've been able to glean. I haven't tried this out but it seems it might work for you. This is [lifted directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) from the reactjs.org docs regarding context. It passed the string name of the theme down.

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('green');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="blue">
        <SomeComponent />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function SomeComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div> 
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext;
  render() {
    return <ThirdComponent theme={this.context} />
  }
}
```

Comment: What you write is the general idea of Context and it is probably ok. But in styled-components there is already a Consumer with its own context, and it is injected in each new styled component. Therefore I would need to edit ThemeProvider in some way or.... get the existing context and create my own provider.... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you understand the idea behind ThemeContext from styled-components. I've passed string "blue" to ThemeContext just to show, that it should not be object and you can use just string.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled, { ThemeContext } from "styled-components";

// Define styled button
const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: ${props => props.theme};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme};
`;

// Define the name of the theme / color (string)
const themeName = "blue";

const ThemedButton = () => {
  // Get the name from context
  const themeName = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return <Button theme={themeName}>Themed color: {themeName}</Button>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeName}>
        <ThemedButton />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-example-with-themecontext-cso55

Comment: Well, your code is accurate as well, still it is not what I was looking for. You used ThemedButton as kind of middleware to apply context value. This means I would have to wrap >each< new styled comp. with such wrapping. I would like to make things happen automatically, from Provider to each styled component.